# Confused about assembly instructions

Tags: assembly, byte, intel, att

I was reading this tutorial on assembly: http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/intel-assembler-on-mac-os-x/ and I came across this basic assembly code:

```
    .text
.globl _main
_main:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    subl $8, %esp
    movl $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

And I kinda understand most of this, but I don't know why `subl $8, %esp` is called. I understand that it subtracts 8 bytes from esp, but I have no idea why that is necessary or why its done. The tutorial said it balances the stack onto a 16-byte boundary, but I don't know what "balancing" the stack means or why using the number 8 makes a 16 byte boundary.

Later in the tutorial is show how to define a function, and call it like this:

```
    .text
.globl _doSomething
_doSomething:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    subl $8, %esp
    nop
    leave
    ret

.globl _main
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
    movl    $3, (%esp)
    call    _doSomething
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

And the tutorial there was "8 to align, 16 for our 4-byte parameter and padding" on this line: `subl $24, %esp`

But if there is a 4 byte parameter and padding, why are we using the number 16? Also, what parameter?

I am on a Intel Core mac, running OS X 10.9.3, compiling with gcc -S -m32 .

I'm very new to assembly, so please make your answers as simple as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf . You can skip the optimization parts for now but it is also a very nice writeup on calling conventions and alignment and such.

Comment: Thanks! I'll start reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a sequence of instructions:

```
1. nop   #call-stack is aligned to 16 bytes (sp is multiple of 16) to start.
2. call function #pushes return address (4 bytes) onto stack.

---(called function)
3. push %ebp #pushes base-pointer (4 bytes) onto stack, which is now 8-byte aligned
---cannot call function that expects to find 16-byte aligned stack---
4. sub $8, %esp #aligns stack to 16 bytes
5. call other_function
```

Comment: How do you know %ebp is 4 bytes?

Comment: `%ebp` is a 4-byte (32-bit) register. It cannot be anything else.

Comment: @addison Well, if the stack was 16-byte (%esp = 0 modulo 16) aligned **before** the `call`-instruction, it will be 4-byte aligned (%esp = 4 modulo 16, to be precise) **at the start** of the called function.

Answer (score 1):

How functions are called on the machine language level is mandated by something called a calling convention that is usually architecture and OS-specific. It is designed so that you can call other functions in an interoperable manner. In this case, the calling convention specified that the called function can expect, that the stack pointer is aligned on the 16-byte boundary when the function is called.

What this means is that the stack pointer (`esp`) is a multiple of 16 bytes.

This is done because certain instructions only work on data that is stored in a memory location that is a multiple of 16, mostly for performance reasons. Other instructions work even on unaligned data but much less efficiently.

Comment: Thanks. So on my first example, when subl $8, %esp is called, how would I know it needs to subtract 8 bytes?

Comment: When your function is called you are able to tell, what the stack alignment will be off 4 bytes for return address (8 on 64-bit) and appropriate number of bytes for every parameter that is passed by stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ask "why does the program not look like this?":

```
_main:
    mov $0, %eax   ; sub %eax, %eax would be more efficient
    ret
```

You are absolutely right. The following four instructions:

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
subl $8, %esp
leave
```

are not useful at all in the example.

If you wrote this assembler function by hand (or post-optimize the C-compiler output) you would not write (or remove) these four instructions.

However most C compilers are optimized for the "normal case": A C function that does nothing but returning a constant value (this is the case here) does not appear very often.

In most C functions (that have variables and real code) however the four instructions shown above make sense! This is why most C compilers always insert these four instructions even if they are not needed in a special case.

I guess the assembly tutorial inserts the four instructions just because in a next step more instructions will be added to the function...